# Faster Ionic state restore

Tags: cordova, github, ionic-framework

When running `ionic state restore`, it will try to reinstall every plugins. This is sometimes every slow especially recently I don't know why github download at dial-up speed and cause some plugin take more than half hour to download.

So, I am thinking, is there anyway to do faster `ionic state restore`? Maybe like only install those plugins that is not available, instead of try to reinstall everything?

Comment: Similar case here : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-state-restore-command-takes-a-lot-of-time-on-the-mac-mini/39137/2?u=hva